# Chrome.tabs.executeScript is not working on some URLS like https://thekindlyones.org/2010/10/13/refusing-to-look-through-galileos-telescope/

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I wrote a content script file in my chrome extension which i want to be injected on every url I visit which is no longer available/can't be reached. But on some URLS which has errors like `This site can’t be reached`, it doesn't work. I tried this URL https://thekindlyones.org/2010/10/13/refusing-to-look-through-galileos-telescope/

Anyone has idea regarding this? Is it supposed to work like this?

Comment: Content scripts don't work on Chrome error pages

Comment: Thank you @IvánNokonoko . I also came to know the same after some researches.